# How to use localhost or other external IPs

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Is there a way to change the localhost path into some other IP. For example: `http://130.147.134.66/xampp/` instead of localhost/xampp

or

If it only reads with `130.147.134.66` how can I change it back to localhost/xampp?

Comment: You mean like in `hosts` file ?

Comment: You can change something within the xampp Apache server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change your ip address to your actual IP address.

For example `127.0.0.1` which is a loopback address to your local machine.

If that 130 address points to your actual machine, then that address should work with minimum configuration.

A good trick is (on unix) editing your /etc/hosts file to point a domain such as mytestingdomain.com to 127.0.0.1

> 127.0.0.1 website.com

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)